# Returning Function in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have come across in difficulty to understand how returning function in Higher Order Functions in Python is working. Can anybody please explain me how following code prints the answer of 25.

```
def create_adder(x):  
    def adder(y):  
        return x + y   
    return adder  

add_15 = create_adder(15)  

print(add_15(10))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def create_adder(x):  
    def adder(y):  
        return x + y   
    return adder
```

This function is ***creating*** and returning a new function. That's what higher-order functions are all about. Functions can be treated like any other data.

```
add_15 = create_adder(15)
```

This line uses the function defined above to define a function that always adds 15. To understand this better you can think of the `adder` nested function defined above as a template. Then `add_15` becomes:

```
def adder(y):  
    return 15 + y
```

The `15` came from `x` passed to `create_adder`

```
print(add_15(10))
```

Finally when you do this, it returns `15 + 10` i.e. `25`

Answer (score 1):

create_adder called. Now x = 15.

```
`add_15 = create_adder(15)  `
```

Function defination here and not going to in.

```
def adder(y):
```

Returns without entering adder function

```
return adder
```

Now add_15(10) called and going to in adder function. y = 10 now.

`print(add_15(10))`

Answer (score 1):

A function is an object too! it can be created, returned, assigned to variables, etc.
The function create_adder requires a parameter x that is going to be the first element of the sum. It then returns a function object.
When create_adder is called with create_adder(15), it uses the number 15 to fill the first element of the sum, then returns a function that receives another number and is assigned to add_15.
When add_15 is called with add_15(10), it uses the number 10 to fill it's requirement for the second element in the sum, then returns its result.